# VB.NET Cycle through specific MDI Children

Tags: vb.net, mdi, children

My application creates MDI Children programatically. I have a frmBrowser as an MDI Child which I create multiple instances of. There are several other MDI children in the MDIParent. How do I only cycle through the frmBrowser MDI children?

```
For Each Child As frmBrowser In frmMain.MdiChildren
    'perform action on child
Next Child
```

The code above gives an error for all the Child that aren't of the type frmBrowser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
For Each Child As frmBrowser In frmMain.MdiChildren.OfType(Of frmBrowser)()
    'perform action on child
Next Child
```